# Relative path not working in Python

Tags: python, linux, relative-path, boto3

My Python script can't resolve the relative path on a Linux server in the following script:

```
import boto3
import os

conn = boto3.client('s3', region_name="eu-west-1", endpoint_url="https://example.com", config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
conn.download_file('mytestbucket22', 'file.csv', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static', 'filecache', 'file.csv'))
```

Error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vcap/app/static/filecache/file.csv.D3e3D7aF'
```

However when I do it like this it works and it saves the file to the path of my script.

```
conn.download_file('mytestbucket22', 'file.csv', 'file.csv')
```

My folder and file structure looks like this:

```
--script.py
--static
----filecache
```

How can I save the file to the folder filecache? Thanks

Comment: Try finding the current path as a string and adding the sub path to it?

Comment: What error do you get when you use the relative path?

Comment: Are permissions for `static` and `static/filecache` correct?

Comment: It simply says that there is no directory with that path. Permissions are correct.

Comment: the current working directory is not the one where you script lives, and by the time your code gets executed it might even not be the one from where you launched the script (if any other code executed befoe yours issued a `chgdir()`). Never relies on cwd, never use relative path, always make sure you use an absolute path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
conn.download_file('mytestbucket22', 'file.csv', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static', 'filecache', 'file.csv'))
```

---

Documentation references for the modules, constants and functions used above:

- The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) modules.
- The [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) constant
- [`os.path.realpath(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) (returns *"the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path"*)
- [`os.path.dirname(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) (returns *"the directory name of pathname `path`"*)
- [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd) (returns *"a string representing the current working directory"*)
- [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) (*"change the current working directory to `path`"*)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get the same error. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vcap/app/static/filecache/file.csv.D3e3D7aF'

Comment: can you please complete info and code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
conn.download_file('mytestbucket22', 'file.csv', os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'static', 'filecache', 'file.csv'))
```